# How to exit while loop when read() blocks

Tags: c, linux, pipe

In a problem given by university we have to `pipe` from a parent process(P1) to its child P2, and afterwards P2 must pipe to another child of P1, the other child is P3. Both P2 and P3 are to be written in c and made into executable files. They will then by `exec`ed by child processes in P1.

P1 writes the numbers 1 to 10000 to `stdout`, P2 reads them through its `stdin`, removes the numbers divisible by 2, and writes the result to its `stdout`. P3 reads those numbers through its `stdin`, filters out the results that are divisible by 3, and writes everything to a file.

I have managed to implement absolutely everything, but my child processes do not end. The reason for this, I believe, is that I have used the following method to read the input in each child:

```
while(n=read(0, &i, sizeof(i))>0)
```

The problem here, as I understand it, is that `read` blocks when it doesn't get any bytes. As P1 writes the 10000 numbers using:

```
for(i=1; i<=10000; i++){
        write(1, &i, sizeof(i));
    }
```

Neither child process ever has any reason to believe that no more data is coming its way. Therefore, each `read` simply blocks waiting for a byte that will never come.

Can anyone suggest a way to overcome this roadblock?

The code of each process is as follows:

Parent:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
        // pipe to send input string from parent
        // Child prints to file 
        int fd1[2];  // Used to store two ends of first pipe
        int fd2[2];  // Used to store two ends of second pipe

    //variables
    int n, i, status1, status2;
    char *args1[]={"./Div2",NULL};
    char *args2[]={"./Div3",NULL};


    //child process ids
        pid_t pid1, pid2;

    //open pipe 1
        if (pipe(fd1)==-1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pipe 1 Failed" );
            return 1;
        }
    //open pipe 2
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pipe 2 Failed" );
            return 1;
        }

    //create child 1    
    pid1 = fork();  
    if(pid1<0){
        printf("Error creating child1\n");
        return(1);
    }
    if(pid1==0){ //child1
        if(close(fd1[1])<0){ //child does not write to pipe 1
            error();
        }
        if(close(fd2[0])<0){ //child does not read from pipe 2
            error();
        }
        dup2(fd1[0], 0); //redirect stdin
        dup2(fd2[1], 1); //redirect stdout
            execvp(args1[0],args1);
        if(close(fd1[0])<0){ //close used pipe
            error();
        }
        if(close(fd2[0])<0){ //close used pipe
            error();
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2<0){
        printf("Error creating child2\n");
        return(1);
    }
    if(pid2==0){ //child2
        if(close(fd1[0])<0){ //child does not use pipe 1
            error();
        }
        if(close(fd1[1])<0){ 
            error();
        }
        if(close(fd2[1])<0){ //child does not write to pipe 2
            error();
        }
        dup2(fd2[0], 0); //redirect stdin
        execvp(args2[0], args2);
        if(close(fd2[0])<0){ //close pipe after use
            error();
        }
        exit(0);
    }


    //parent
    //parent doesn't read from the pipe
    if(close(fd1[0])<0){
    error();
    }
    if(close(fd2[0])<0){
    error();
    }
    if(close(fd2[1])<0){
    error();
    }
    dup2(fd1[1], 1); //redirect stdout
    for(i=1; i<=10000; i++){
        write(1, &i, sizeof(i));
    }
    if(close(fd1[1])<0){
    error();
    }
    int returnedPID1=waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0);
    if(returnedPID1==pid1){
    printf("Parent waited for child as predicted\n");
    }
    int returnedPID2=waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
    if(returnedPID2==pid2){
    printf("Parent waited for child as predicted\n");
    }
    _exit(0);

}
```

P2 (includes excluded)

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    while((n=read(0, &i, 4))>0){
        if((i%2)!=0){
            write(1, &i, sizeof(i));
        }   
    }
    return;
}
```

P3

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    char tmp[12] = {0x0};
    char *arg[]= {"/home/eric/Documents/pr3/test.txt"};
    int fp = open(arg[0], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
        if(fp<0){
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            _exit(1);
        }

    while((n=read(0, &i, 4))>0){
        if((i%3)!=0){
            sprintf(tmp,"%11d", i);
            write(fp, tmp, strlen(tmp));
        }   
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: To begin with, `n=read(...)>0` will not work as you apparently expect, as it is equal to `n = (read(...) > 0)`. I.e. it assign the result of the *comparison* to `n`.

Comment: As for breaking the loop when `read` blocks, that's kind of impossible since you're stuck in the `read` call. You can however poll descriptors to see if calling `read` will block.  One such way is to use the [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) call.

Comment: `while(n=read(0, &i, sizeof(i))>0)` --> `while((n=read(0, &i, sizeof i )) > 0)`

Comment: When all writers to a pipe are closed, then the first attempt to `read` will return 0 for EOF. Any future `read`s cause SIGPIPE, which defaults to killing the process; failing that, `read` returns and sets `errno` to `EPIPE`. If `read` is blocking, that implies that some writer is still open. See [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) for more info.

Comment: Indeed @DanielH it does seem that the problem was that some descriptors were still open and no 0 was ever returned. I also re-wrote the condition according to your advice, chux, thanks!

Comment: A read will never cause a SIGPIPE.  Subsequent reads will immediately return 0 (or -1).  Only writes can generate a SIGPIPE.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are correct; I got confused, and you can't edit old comments.

Comment: Suggest using `select()` with a timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except in case of error, exec never returns.  So when you write:

```
    execvp(args1[0],args1);
    if(close(fd1[0])<0){ //close used pipe
        error();
    }
```

you are wrong to expect the file descriptor to be closed.  Close them before you exec.  They are getting left open.  Although in your particular case the problem is that the parent never closes fd 1.  The parent has two file descriptors that are writing into the pipe ( `fd[1]` and `1`), and you need to close them both before the child reading the pipe will finish.

Comment: "exec never returns." --> "... normally don’t return, ... A value of -1 is returned in the event of a failure."